# Hashmap in hash map try to insert something

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my hashmap:

```
protected HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>> prisonsPlayers = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>>();
```

I try to insert something in it with:

```
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getWorld(), (HashMap<player.getName(), player>));
```

Erorr I get:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression
    - Syntax error on token ")", invalid 
     Expression
```

I know I do something wrong but however I try, what ever I do I don't know how to insert that data to my hashmap.

Comment: No, generics are compile time, not run time. You can't use the value returned by a method as a type argument. Please also review Java syntax. Actually, scrap everything you know about generics, and start from a Java generics tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getWorld(), (HashMap<player.getName(), player>));
```

Should be like this

```
Map<String, Player> map  = new HashMap<String, Player>();
map.put(player.getName(),player);  
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getWorld(), map);
```

Comment: actualy i am using more hashmaps in the code, like so are u sure?:
 protected HashMap<String, Player> freePlayers = new HashMap<String, Player>();
 
 protected HashMap<String, Player> loggedPlayers = new HashMap<String, Player>();
 
 protected HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>> prisonsPlayers = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>>();

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error (or maybe logic, too?)

```
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getWorld(), (HashMap<player.getName(), player>));
```

Try doing this

```
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getWorld(), (new HashMap<String, Player>()));
prisonsPlayers.get(player.getWorld()).put(player.getName(), player);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but your code mark me word "put" and say: Link all references for a local rename (does not change references 
 in other files)

Answer (score 0):

Prabhkaran is exactly right, has answer will work.

The code

```
HashMap<player.getName(), player>
```

is not valid, because you are supplying objects into the HashMap generic parameters, and they should be class definitions.

Example:

```
// Construct a HashMap with can contain Strings as keys and values
HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// add Strings to my hashmap
mymap.put("hello","world");
```

is OK, but

```
// compilation failure!
new HashMap<"Hello","World">();
```

is not.